# Will a Motorola DEFY+ sync with my Outlook calendar and contacts?

Tags: sync, calendar, outlook, motorola-defy

I'd like to buy a Motorola DEFY+ as it fits my needs almost perfectly. However, I read some test reviews which are claiming that the Outlook sync options are quite weak.

Does anyone know if this phone will synchronize with my local Outlook calendar and contacts? Are there any known problems which might occur during the synchronization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I bought the Motorola Defy+ and I'm disapointed, as it seems there's synchronization is only possible via Google account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you described, the situation looks quite disappointing.